# Compilation error in template when const is removed

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, implicit-conversion

```
template<typename T>
void func(const T &x) {
    cout << "base template "<<x<<"\n";
}

template<>
void func(const int &x) {
    cout << "int specialization "<<x<<"\n";
}

template<>
void func(const double &x) {
    cout << "double specialization "<<x<<"\n";
}

int main() {
    int five = 5;
    func(five); // prints int specialization 5
    double d = 3.14;
    func<int>(d); // prints int specialization 3
}
```

Now with `const` removed

```
template<typename T>
void func( T &x) {
    cout << "base template "<<x<<"\n";
}

template<>
void func( int &x) {
    cout << "int specialization "<<x<<"\n";
}

template<>
void func( double &x) {
    cout << "double specialization "<<x<<"\n";
}

int main() {
    int five = 5;
    func(five); // prints int specialization 5
    double d = 3.14;
    func<int>(d); // throws compile error
}
```

Why do I get a compilation error in `func<int>(d)` where as in the `const` version everything compiled fine ?

Error   C2664   'void func(int &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to 'int &'

I came across this when I was trying out some examples on my own for template specialization.

I'm looking for reading links and posts that might be helpful.

Comment: Removing the `const` allows to modify `x`, and this is a problem because the `d` that you pass as an argument is not actually an `int` (but a `double`). Using `const` allows to bind to a temporary that is the result of converting yout `double d` to `int`.

Comment: Early in the morning, and I haven't checked, but I suspect that templates are a distraction here. Try a single function `void func(int&)` and call it with `func(d);` .

Comment: please include the compiler error in the question. I holds valuabe information

Comment: You could provide an explicit temporary to work around the language constraint. `template <typename T> struct temp { T var; temp(T value) : var{value} {} operator T&() { return var; } };` and then call the function by `func<int>(temp<int>(d));`. Don't do this in real code; shown here for educational purposes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is not actually related to templates:

Your `double d` needs to be converted to an `int` in order to be an argument for a function expecting an `int` reference.

But since the converted `int` is a temporary (i.e. a R-value) it cannot be bound to an `int &`, but only to a `const int &`.

You can observe this without any template:

```
void func1(const int& x) 
{
}

void func2(int& x) 
{
}

int main() 
{
    double d = 3.14;
    func1(d);   // This compiles.
    func2(d);   // This does not. Error on MSVC: cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to 'int &'
}
```